# What are the ways to send sms through a java application?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm new to this concept of sending sms through java application, can you people help me by saying what are all the ways to send sms from an application

Comment: Is your application web? Does it have to run locally? Please provide more details.

Comment: are you using a physical GSM modem or a sms sending gateway ? In the first case it's enough write the correct AT commands on the device, in the second case it depends on your particulare SMS Sending Gateway

Comment: I want to use gateway not GSM modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send sms through Java but for that you need to sms gateway provider. There are some gateway providers which allow you to send sms free  of cost like way2ms, indyarocks etc.

For indyarocks you can refer the following code :

```
String email = "//your mail id"; //http://www.indyarocks.com/ 
String user = "//indyarocks user id";    
String pass = "//indyarocks password";
String number = ""; //no on which sms is to be send   
String msg = "";//message to be send
try{
       try {
                String mURL;
                mURL = "http://www.onl9class.com/smsapi/smsir.php?email=" + email + "&user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass + "&number=" + number + "&msg=" + URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");
                URL url = new URL(mURL);
                BufferedReader reader = null;            
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
                String aline;
                aline = reader.readLine();
                while (aline != "") 
                {     
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+aline);
                    break;
                }
                if (reader != null) 
                {
                    try 
                    {                    
                        reader.close();                    
                    } finally  
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error ");
                    }
                }            
            } catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Error "+ex);
                }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            }
```

Comment: ya i've got the account in way2sms and i surfed for sample programs also in google.I've tried with that but i couldn't get any propers output

Comment: @SasiDunston you can refer the code i have posted for indyarocks.

Comment: i'm not able to find the code you have posted on the links Indyarocks @gau123

Comment: hav u looked at my edited answer ??

Comment: ya i've got the code and its working correctly but its not delivering the message @gau123

Comment: try sending sms on any other number because its working for me

Comment: should i've to add 91- or +91 before the number or what its not working for me @gau123

Comment: you don't need to add 91 or +91..is it printing anything on the console output window ? @SasiDunston

Comment: its executing the finally block printing Error

Comment: if it is just printing the word "Error" then message must have been sent..it indicates successful message delivery..check the number on which you are sending sms for "DND User"..if it is, then message will not be delivered..these gateways don't send messages to DND Users

Comment: thing hat it worked for one time and not on another time along with that i need know how it works can you send me a detailed instructions of how it works dunston08@gmail.com

Comment: @gau123 this is what i get when the above code executed `Error java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL` and message is not received

Comment: @sankrish have u registered on indyarocks.com because in the above code you have to enter your indyarocks id, password and email that you have registered over there

Comment: yeah i have registered

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can send sms by java application.but you need to have a sms sending gateway with you.

Answer (score 1):

ESBs like Mule, Camel or Spring Integration include connectors for this.

Take a look at:

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/twilio-cloud-connector-2/

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration-smpp/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/